# What is the meaning of "salvus" in this sentence about music?

Tags: medieval-latin, word-usage, music, chant

[*Instituta Patrum de modo psallendi*](https://chmtl.indiana.edu/tml/13th/PATPSAL) is a [High Medieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Middle_Ages) document, allegedly based on circulated precepts of [Bernard of Clairveaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Clairvaux), and perhaps other church figures as well. It enjoins church communities to sing [psalm tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciting_tone) in a certain way.

The first half of a psalm verse is to be sung in one breath, followed by a pause to catch breath. Then the second half of the verse is to be "*deponendus*" to the psalm tone's musical cadence, where "*deponere*" here means lowering the music in pitch from its psalm tone 'tenor' to its final pitch by a 5- or 6-note cadence:

> Facta pausa, quod de versu restat, morosiori modulatione deponatur **salvo tono**.
>
> The pause having been made, let what remains in the verse be laid down **to/by the safe(?) tone** with slower mensuration.

*Salvo tono*? What does that mean? How is one to read this sentence, assuming there is no typo or missing word?

Answer (score 3):

Ablative phrases with *salvus* are commonly used to mean "preserving, maintaining, without violating" ([see L&S **I.B**](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/salvus)):

- *salvā fidē, cōnscientiā* ("staying true to one's honour, conscience")
- *salvō ōrdine, sēnsū* ("in the same order, without changing the meaning")

There's a whole battery of different definitions for [*tonus*](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=LmL&lemid=T00243), but the meaning intended here appears to be "pitch" (it's hardly "melody"). The instruction would then be to continue after the pause on the same note, "preserving the pitch".

Comment: Formal logic also has the common fixed phrase *[salva veritate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salva_veritate)* for describing the ability to always substitute identical terms in direct reference contexts within a proposition, "the truth (value) being preserved." (So, for example, if `Paris`=`Alexander` then `Alexander is the Trojan prince who slew Achilles` has the same truth value as `Paris is the Trojan prince who slew Achillles`, etc. )

Comment: The meaning of _tonus_ in this document _is_ certainly the melody of the psalm tone and not a singular note pitch. Documents on music from the Carolingian era onward often mean this signification when they are talking about psalmody, some when talking about the church modes in general.

Comment: @Coemgenus I think it's somewhat more complicated than that. From the wikipedia article: "before returning to the **reciting tone** until the mediant. After the mediant, the second part of the psalm verse is sung on the **reciting tone** until the last few words, which are sung to a cadential formula called the termination." I think this is precisely what this sentence says - the *mediant* is the *pausa*, and the instruction is to continue the psalm "on the same reciting tone = pitch".

Comment: Admittedly it could be referring not to the entire second part but only to the "termination". Do you know if a second pause is made in psalmody between the second part and the termination? This sounds unlikely; and if so, I don't see how it makes sense to instruct the singers to "preserve the melody" while already singing the termination of that melody. So I think that "psalm tone" here is the same as "singular note pitch" because psalm tones are built around a singular note pitch.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian If your answer is correct, then the document is saying "After the pause" (the breath or beat rest after the mediant cadence) "let the remainder of the verse be 'deposed' (dropped in pitch, mensurated downward, cadenced), with the tone preserved". Hmm ... what he means by "with the tone preserved" is still vague. He could mean keeping the cadence in the Psalm's Antiphon mode, but, given the rest of the paragraph, he more likely means keeping the cantors in rhythmical unison and not deviating. However ...

Comment: ... I disagree with your interpretation of "tonus" for three reasons. 1) "Deponere" is not just underlay. In the Latin documents as a whole, it means to drop the pitch. That makes sense only on a cadence, not a reciting note. 2) "Morosior" refers to a protraction in tempo class from "metrum" to "rhythmus", which happens between the reciting note and cadence, where "metrum" refers to the 2-by-2-beat meter of the cadences and "rhythmus" to the 1-by-1-beat meterless rhythm of the reciting note. But that is another topic. ...

Comment: ... 3) The next paragraph (see the link) is clear that "tonus" is the cadence: "Omnis tonorum depositio in finalibus, mediis vel ultimis, non est secundum accentum verbi, sed secundum musicalem melodiam toni facienda." There is no "musicalis melodia" in the reciting note. And again, "Ideoque si tonaliter finis versuum deponitur, ... ut sunt sex syllabae 'Saeculorum Amen', ita sex conformentur notis toni in depositione verborum et syllabarum." The tenor, after all, does not define the "notes of the tone". The cadence does.

Comment: I think you're drawing a false distinction. He means that the cadence, meaning the formulaic descending melody, should start at the same pitch as before the pause. Rhythmical unison has nothing to do with the meaning of 'tonus'. The reciting tone is what the psalm is defined around, including departures, and specifically "lowering", the cadence. You "lower the reciting tone down", and what reciting tone you start with defines the final cadence.—I'm totally unfamiliar with that distinction between metrum and rhytmus you're referring to so I don't see any special sense in that "morosior".

Comment: I will recapitulate: there's no difference between *tonus* meaning "reciting tone" and it meaning "cadence" in this instance because there were 8 cadences, each defined around a single reciting tone, or as Wikipedia puts it, each **psalm tone** has its own associated **gregorian mode** which defines the **cadence** among other things. By saying *tonus* the writer instructs the singers to preserve the tone of the main psalm, the mode, and its particular type of cadence, as opposed to mixing and matching them.